# Testing authentication in Django

Tags: django, ldap

I'm trying to implement LDAP authentication in a test Django project. I think I've done all the configuration correctly (I'm using the django_ldap_auth package) and I want to test the authentication without having to create a whole site with log in etc. Is that possible ? FYI, I'm only doing this as a part of making LDAP the main authentication method at my company, and have to plug the functionality into a large project.

I've tried running the server on localhost and ssh-ing through the terminal, but apparently that only logs me onto my own computer, I think :) (not an experienced Linux user).

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to your Django project folder and Start the python interpreter with

```
python manage.py shell
```

and then do,

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend

ldapobj = LDAPBackend()
user = ldapobj.populate_user(<LDAP username of an existing user>)
user.is_anonymous()
```

if the last function call returns false then it your LDAP auth module works as expected.

edit:

Run the Python interpreter as above and,

```
import ldap
server = 'ldap://<your server ip>'
user_dn = '<dn for a known user>'
password = '<his or her password>'
con = ldap.initialize(server)
con.simple_bind_s(user_dn, password)
```

This will return SERVER_DOWN: {'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"} exception, if you can't connect to the LDAP sever.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the is_anonymous() function call didn't return anything since "user" was a none object (didn't work). Your answer however showed me how I might use the class functions to test the functionality. I'm trying to see whether I'm able to connect to the LDAP server at all, but I've haven't been able to figure it out. Any ideas ?

Comment: If you are sure your ldap server is running, Then follow the edit in question.

Comment: Thanks again, I can connect to the server, but the module is still not working. I have been trying to trace the error through the code, unsuccessfully (lot of functions defined here and there). The thing that bugs me the most is that I can't seem to find where my settings for ldap in settings.py are imported, since these are of course essential for this to work. I don't think I can ask for any more of your help though, guess I'll try and figure this out.

Comment: put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` somewhere in the LDAP module code and step through the code execution. Then you might find a clue to where it gets stuck.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that this is currently working and the sites here will soon have LDAP authentication. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The connection is OK for me but not the authentication .. I got this error (ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH must be an LDAPSearch instance.) after doing this : (user = ldapobj.populate_user(<LDAP username of an existing user>)) .. Thanks for your help

Comment: @vim I had the same problem as the one who posted the question. I tried the edit and got a response but I do not know what it is. Here is what I got after ```con.simple_bind_s(user_dn,password)``` (97, [], 1, [])