# Configuring LDAP

Tags: django, ldap, server

My app I am building requires LDAP authentification. I am hosting my app through apache and I am using ssl...if that helps

I've installed all of the libraries and followed the basic config steps,  but after trying a few shell related tests I've been unable to even connect to my ldap server.

I've never done this before so any help is greatly appreciated.

Let me know if I should post any extra material.

Main tutorial: https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/_static/versions/1.0.19/index.html

Test I've used so far: [Testing authentication in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523270/testing-authentication-in-django)

Upon changing ldap://128.114.119.108:636 to ldaps://128.114.119.108:636 since ssl

```
>>> import ldap
>>> server = 'ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:qqq'
>>> user_dn = 'uid=ajanakos,ou=people,dc=ucsc,dc=edu'
>>> password = 'xxxxxxxxx'
>>> con = ldap.initialize(server)
>>> con.simple_bind_s(user_dn, password)
SERVER_DOWN: {'info': 'TLS: hostname does not match CN in peer certificate', 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
```

settings.py

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:qqq"

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=people,dc=ucsc,dc=edu", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

views.py - login function

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import search
from forms import Form
from dmca import settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import credentials as c
import base64
import psycopg2
import time
import datetime

# Create your views here.

def Login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print 'text'
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/lookup')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Inactive user.")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

     return render(request, "dmca_app/login.html", {})
```

Comment: Can you link us to the tutorial(s) you're following, and show us what response you get when you try to connect?

Comment: My main tutorial: https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/_static/versions/1.0.19/index.html

Comment: Thanks! So, when you say that you can't even connect--what kind of message do you get on the shell?

Comment: if you read the testing link i posted.. for the 1st method the anonymous function didnt exist, and the second method didnt work.. ill post what I actually type in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that you are trying to connect to the LDAP server, using LDAPS, i.e. LDAP over TLS. This requires that you are configuring a TrustStore that contains at least the certificates to verify the server's certificate.

Comment: YES Ty. I needed to use the hostname not the IP to agree with the cert :))))

Comment: @ajanakos Can you post your working settings for `ldaps`?